# CSS Styling - DIV - How to prevent the div element to skip to the next line?

Tags: css

For my two div elements below, how would I prevent the div element to skip to the next line?

```
<div class = "one">
  One
  <div class = "two">
    Two
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in:

```
One
Two
```

**Question: How do I make it come in one row so it is as follows:**

```
OneTwo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple...

```
   .two {
       display:inline-block;
    }
```

And my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/LfN9C/6/

Answer (score 0):

Change the second `div` to a `span`:

```
  <span class = "two">
    Two
  </span>
```

Two reasons:

- It's doesn't add any extra CSS
- It's more "semantic" to have a `span` contained inside of a `div` (rather than two `div`s hacked to fit into one another)

Hope this helps!

Here's a link to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/4HxhV/

Answer (score 0):

The big issue is you need to wrap these so that you can display them correctly. I would move .two out of one. Then put class .one and .two inside .wrapper so that it can contain them. Then place display: inline-block on .wrapper div. See my example.
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class = "one">
    One
   </div>
   <div class = "two">
    Two
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```